# Keep MooTools Accordion closed on initial Page Laod

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, accordion

I have an Accordion built with MooTools which works great.

***jsfiddle example:*** http://jsfiddle.net/T6WX7/

However, **can someone explain how I update this script so my accordion remains closed when the page initially loads**.

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:
`display: -1,`
to the attributes.

Found the answer here: http://davidwalsh.name/simple-mootools-accordion#comments

Joy :-D

Answer (score 1):

Actually this should work:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
new Accordion($$('div.toggler'), $$('div.accordion'), {
 alwaysHide: true,
 display: false,
 opacity: false
 });
});
```

display:false should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianRomeni/T6WX7/1/